# Alternative to for loop with "dynamic" variables with R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am new to StackOverflow even though it's been a while I play with R. I am struggling with a problem for which I was not able to find any answer on the site. Please correct me if I my quest was not enough accurate.

I have two 3d arrays, in this simplified case 256x256x200. First one is a field, the second one is made of indices, spanning from 1 to 8. I want to compute the average on each vertical level according to the values and the counts of the indices, i.e. the average the the field for 200 levels for each index (from 1 to 8). This should be done only if there are enough counts of the indices (i.e. an if condition within the loop). My output must be a matrix of 8x200.

For the example I create two random arrays. Here below there is the basic code I am using:

```
nz=200
lev=1:nz
indices=8
var0=array(rnorm(256*256*nz),dim=c(256,256,nz))
#octo=array(sample(1:indices),dim=c(256,256,nz)) 
octo=array(sample(1:indices,size=256*256*nz,replace=T),dim=c(256,256,nz))
counts=apply(octo,3,function(x) table(factor(x,levels=1:indices)))
#thr=0.1
thr=0.125
np=length(var0[,1,1])*length(var0[1,,1])
profile=array(NA,dim=c(nz,indices))


t0=proc.time()
for (i in 1:indices)
{
    for (z in 1:length(lev)) 
    {
       if (counts[i,z]/np>thr) 
       {v0=var0[,,z];  profile[z,i]=counts[i,z]/np*mean(v0[octo[,,z]==i],na.rm=T)} 
    }
}
print(proc.time()-t0)

user  system elapsed 
5.169   0.001   5.170
```

I tried with apply family of functions but I am not able to write it down in a reasonable and efficient way, considering that I need that each computation takes into account a "dynamic" variable that changes its level (i.e. **octo** and **counts** vars). My real case is made by way bigger matrices and this should be done on dozens of fields, thus time is pretty relevant.
Are you aware of any faster alternatives?
Many thanks for any help!

EDIT: I corrected the original definition of **octo** and I adjusted the threshold **thr**. In this way the if condition makes sense, since it is not always respected.

Comment: Have you considered melting the data? If you truly have dynamic values, perhaps a tidy structure would make it cleaner.

Comment: Also, isn't counts just a 8x200 matrix of 8192 repeating? is the definition of octo / the definition of counts correct?

Comment: @shape It is... I thought that was weird too...

Comment: @shape thanks for your comments! yes you are totally right, octo is ill-defined but its definition is just a test case to be used a fast example.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `data.table` reshape solution that avoids loops and or apply statements:

```
nz=200
lev=1:nz
indices=8
var0=array(rnorm(256*256*nz),dim=c(256,256,nz))
octo=array(sample(1:indices),dim=c(256,256,nz))
counts=apply(octo,3,function(x) table(factor(x,levels=1:indices)))
thr=0.1
np=length(var0[,1,1])*length(var0[1,,1])
profile=array(NA,dim=c(nz,indices))


# From here load data.table to do the manipulation
# reshape2 to convert back into a matrix at the end
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

# Take the data long and convert to data.table
var01 <- setDT(melt(var0))
octo1 <- setDT(melt(octo))

# Join the data to get corresponding data
# EDIT, it currently works, but I think that's because all data is defined
# adding nomatch in case of missing data
octo1 <- octo1[var01, on = c('Var1','Var2','Var3'), nomatch = NA] 

# Make our calculation grouping by the vertical dimension and the value
profile <- octo1[,if(.N/np > thr) .N / np * mean(i.value, na.rm = TRUE) else NA, by = .(value,Var3)]

# Recast to matrix
profile <- acast(profile, value ~ Var3, mean, value.var = 'V1')
```

Comment: @PaoloDavini Yeah, this is a calculation that seems easier to visualize in long format. Lookups inside corresponding tensors get hairy.

Comment: Are you sure this works correctly? If I run this code, all I get is columns containing 1:8

Comment: @parksw3 fixed, the acast at the end should have the value column, it was calculating the mean of a different column

Comment: In this case, the mean in the acast doesn't actually do anything, since there should only be one combination of each index and level (value and var3 respectively), but acast requires a function that takes many to 1

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be faster on my machine:

```
profile2 <- sapply(lev, function(i){
    v0 <- var0[,,i]
    mV <- sapply(1:indices, function(j){
        mean(v0[octo[,,i] == j], na.rm = TRUE)
    })
    counts[,i]/np*mV
})
profile2[counts/np > thr] <- NA
profile2<- t(profile2)

all.equal(profile, profile2)
## TRUE
```

I tried comparing them with `microbenchmark` package but it takes fairly long... Here's a quick comparison I did with `rbenchmark` package

```
f1 <- function(){
    for (i in 1:indices){
        for (z in 1:length(lev)) {
            if (counts[i,z]/np>thr){
                v0=var0[,,z];  profile[z,i]=counts[i,z]/np*mean(v0[octo[,,z]==i],na.rm=T)
            } 
        }
    }
}

f2 <- function(){
    prof <- sapply(lev, function(i){
        v0 <- var0[,,i]
        mV <- sapply(1:indices, function(j){
            mean(v0[octo[,,i] == j], na.rm = TRUE)
        })
        counts[,i]/np*mV
    })
    profile2[counts/np > thr] <- NA
    profile2<- t(profile2)
}

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(f1(), f2(), replications = 10)
```

I put both codes into a function and tested. Here's the result:

```
##   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
## 1 f1()           10   89.03    1.342     85.15     1.72
## 2 f2()           10   66.34    1.000     61.50     0.75
```

Comment: this sounds great, many thanks. I was not used to the nesting of sapply, but it is a great choice. At a first glance on my machine it takes about the half to run. I will do some benchmarking asap. The only pity is that actually it is doing the computation also for the "useless" case where **thr** is not reached.

Comment: @PaoloDavini yeah... I just thought about that... Let me see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I find a good solution with `sapply` including the **thr**

```
f1<-function()
{   
for (i in 1:indices)
{
for (z in 1:length(lev)) {if (counts[i,z]/np>thr) {v0=var0[,,z]; profile[z,i]=counts[i,z]/np*mean(v0[octo[,,z]==i],na.rm=T) } }
}
return(profile)
}

f2<-function()
{
profile=sapply(lev, function(i) {
            v0=var0[,,i];
            mV=sapply(1:indices, function(j) {mean(v0[octo[,,i] == j], na.rm = TRUE)})
            counts[,i]/np*mV
    })

profile[counts/np <= thr]=NA
profile<-matrix(profile, nz, indices, byrow = TRUE)
return(profile)
}

f3<-function()
{
profile=sapply(lev, function(i) {
            v0=var0[,,i];
            mV=sapply(1:indices, function(j) {if (counts[j,i]/np>thr) {mean(v0[octo[,,i] == j], na.rm = TRUE)} else {NA}})
            counts[,i]/np*mV
    })

profile<-matrix(profile, nz, indices, byrow = TRUE)
return(profile)
}
```

Actually f1() is the original, f2() is the @parksw3 one and f3() is my version slightly improved.

```
benchmark(f1(),f2(),f3(),replications=10)

test   replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child  sys.child
1 f1()           10  27.382    1.411    27.375        0          0         0
2 f2()           10  35.195    1.814    35.186        0          0         0
3 f3()           10  19.403    1.000    19.392        0          0         0
```

In this way it is always faster than the standard loop. The `data.table` is likely faster but it requires a full change of data structure that I cannot perform for the moment. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't this mean that sapply is slower than the original method? f2 seemed to be running faster on my machine. Also, your method of handling NA still performs unnecessary computation. I haven't figured that out yet...

Comment: f2 is faster than f1 when the if condition is always satisfied... f3 uses sapply but avoids the average computation, is always faster than f1 and it will "converge" to f2 when the if condition is always satisfied...